# Prevent hotlinking but allow Facebook - MaxCDN

Tags: facebook, cdn, hotlinking

I've recently enabled hotlink protection on MaxCDN, using what is known as Referer Access Control whitelisting.

I've enabled my own domains and my CDN domain, and it's working very nicely, however, when I try to share an image on social media, the og:image is not being picked up correctly.

Using the Facebook Debugger, I can see that an error is being thrown on the og:image

"Provided og:image URL, https://cdn.collectiveray.com/images/webdesign/web_design_blogs.jpg could not be processed as an image because it has an invalid content type."

I believe the problem is that the Facebook crawler is not in the whitelist. I've allow facebook.com, *.facebook.com, fbcdn.com, *.fbcdn.com, fbcdn.net, *.fbcdn.net, yet I am still unable to resolve the above error.

Would anybody know which are the exact domains to whitelist to allow social networks, both Facebook and others, to be able to access the images directly via their CDN URL?

TIA
David

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think the Facebook scraper sends any referrer.

But you can identify it based on the User-Agent it sends, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler

Details on how to set this up for MaxCDN here, https://www.maxcdn.com/one/tutorial/blank-referers-social-networks/

Comment: These are EdgeRules and are not available unless you pay a significantly higher plan.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with their pricing model, I just quickly googled that. But their description there seems to confirm what I said initially - those bots are likely to not send any referrer in the first place. If you can’t use the User Agent, maybe you can allow specific IPs? The Facebook documentation explains how to get a list of IP addresses their scraper might use, so if you can add exceptions based on that, that should also work. (Although those IPs can change frequently, so you’d have to find a way to update your MaxCDN config regularly.)